# Why would the jQuery selector return null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing javascript for a page that was built using a WYSIWYG. No, I cannot at present go in and change the IDs or really tweak the DOM.

This is the DOM element I'm trying to select (this was created by the WYSIWYG).

```
<td nowrap="true" align="left" id="vW2070;" name="vW2070;" style="padding-left: 2pt; padding-right: 2pt; border-left: 1pt solid black; cursor: auto; background-color: rgb(164, 194, 64); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class=" nAll selected" selected="1" sn="itemList">TOP 5</td>
```

Currently in my javascript the ID I'm trying to get is `#vW2070;`. For some reason `document.getElementById("vW2070;")` returns perfectly but `$("#vW2070;")` returns null. Why is this? I need to use the jQuery selector.

The function in question is ran on `$(document).ready`.

I've never seen anything like this.

Thank you, all.

**EDIT:** Without the semi-colon it doesn't pick it up either. The semi-colon is literally in the ID attribute on the element thanks to the WYSIWYG.

Comment: Why the semicolons? Are they actually part of the selector?

Comment: jquery doesn't ignore `;`, so `$("#vW2070;")` should be `$("#vW2070")`

Comment: Does the ID really have a semi-colon in it?

Comment: it returns a literal `null`? or an empty jquery set? because if its the former, are you use that $ is an alias for jQuery and not another js framework?

Comment: Yes, the ID really does have a semi-colon in it.

Comment: *"The semi-colon is literally in the ID attribute"*.  Then I think you'll need an attribute filter `$('div[id="vW2070;"]')` to ensure cross browser functionality.

Comment: Next time try to ask a full question including the CMS and preferably a jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can escape the semicolon like this:

```
$("#vW2070\\;") //Use one backslash to escape the semicolon for the Sizzle parser and the other to escape the first backslash for the javascript parser, so two in total
```

or

```
$(document.getElementById("#vW2070;")).jquerystuff(...);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HTyQC/

Also, [a relevant link](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) on how versatile the id attribute is.

Comment: While your solution *should* work, for some reason when I escape it, it still fails. I've realized now that document.getElementById("vW2070;") returns null as well. I have no idea why. This is insane... I'm going to mark this answer as correct. When I figure out what's wrong with my code and my crazy situation I'll post the solution here.

Comment: Again... trust me... I would've never used it. It's a tool called MicroStrategy which tracks analytics data. I was recently hired in and the site had already been built using their WYSIWYG tool. Phase 2 (next year) is for me to re-do the whole thing :) I can't wait. We're doing it this way now to meet a deadline. I couldn't exactly re-write the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't edit your ID that has a semicolon, try escaping it in the selector, like so:

```
$("#vW2070\\;")
```

Escaping here is nothing more than adding the "\ \" before the semicolon.

Here's some more insight: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ; your shouldn't need it

```
$("#vW2070")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the semi-colon `$("#vW2070;")` to `$("#vW2070")`

Are you not getting an error message? In chrome you should get `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ;`

Answer (score 1):

you should try escaping `";"` by using `"\"`

change `$("#vW2070;")` to `$("#vW2070\\;")`

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/28cZu/

Answer (score 1):

If your element's `id` really does have a semi-colon in it, then <strike>[technically its invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).</strike>

**Edit:** The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) doesn't appear to preclude any characters other than spaces.

You can just espace the semi-colon with a double backslash `#vW2070\\;`

Otherwise, just drop the semi-colon from your selector code.

Answer (score 0):

It is jquery bug or we can say limitation in current jquery version. It will not allow    ';' in ID.